# How to check the HttpSession exists in Filter

Tags: java, web, httpsession, spring-session

I am having a javax.servlet.Filter in which I want to redirect to login page if HttpSession is new and redirect to the logout page if HttpSession expired and to some other page if HttpSession is present.

```
The login and logout pages are external pages. My sample method is given below

    @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) arg0;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) arg1;

    if (request.getSession(false) == null) { 
        response.sendRedirect("login page");
    } else if (request.getRequestedSessionId() != null && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
        response.sendRedirect("logout page");
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }    

}
```

The problem is after session expired, the logout page doesn't renders. How to get this to work?

Comment: How can I differentiate if it is the new session or the expired session?

Answer (score 0):

If the session has expired, `getSession(false)` returns null, so you redirect to the login page. Your second `if` should be before the first one.

Answer (score 0):

or maybe you can try

```
getSession().isNew()
```